# Trying to read a text file using regex to check each line

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a program that will allow a user to input a name of a movie and the program would then generate the date associated with. I have a text file that has date and the movies that pertain to it. I am reading the file via Scanner and I created a movie class that stores an ArrayList and String for movies and date, respectively. I am having trouble with reading the files. Can anyone please assist me. Thank you!

Here is a part of the text file:

```
10/1/2014   
    Der Anstandige
    "Men, Women and Children"
    Nas: Time is Illmatic

10/2/2014   
    Bang Bang
    Haider

10/3/2014   
    Annabelle
    Bitter Honey
    Breakup Buddies
    La chambre bleue
    Drive Hard
    Gone Girl
    The Good Lie
    A Good Marriage
    The Hero of Color City
    Inner Demons
    Left Behind
    Libertador
    The Supreme Price
```

Here is my movie class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class movie
{
    private ArrayList<String> movies;
    private String date;

    public movie(ArrayList<String> movies, String date)
    {
        this.movies = movies;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getMovies()
    {
        return movies;
    }
}
```

Here is the readFile class

```
package Read;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readFile
{
    public static List<movie> movies;
    public static String realPath;
    public static ArrayList<String> mov;
    public static String j;
    public static String i;

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        //movies = new ArrayList<movie>();
        realPath = "movie_release_dates.txt";
        File f = new File(realPath);
        try
        {
            String regex1 = "[^(0-9).+]";
            String regex2 = "[^0-9$]";

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

            while (sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                //movies
                if(!sc.nextLine().matches(regex2))
                {
                    i = sc.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Hello2");
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                //date
                while(sc.nextLine().matches(regex1))
                {
                    System.out.println("Hello3");
                    if(!sc.nextLine().matches(regex1))
                    {
                        j = sc.nextLine();
                        mov.add(sc.nextLine());
                        System.out.println("Hello4");
                    }
                }
                movie movie = new movie(mov,i);
                movies.add(movie);
            }

        //   sc.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("CANT");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "you're having trouble?" Is an exception being thrown? If so what exception and where? Is it doing something that's not expected, or not doing something that is, if so what is it?

Comment: @drewmoore My bad, I'm not getting the Strings for each line. So the problem is with my code, in particular the regex to isolate the date and store it and also isolating the movie list for that particular date.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.stackoverflow.q26269799;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFile {
    public static List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    public static String realPath;
    public static ArrayList<String> mov;
    public static String j;
    public static String i;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //movies = new ArrayList<movie>();
        realPath = "movie_release_dates.txt";
        File f = new File(realPath);
        if ( !f.exists()) {
            System.err.println("file path not specified");
        }
        try {
            String regex1 = "[^(0-9).+]";
            String regex2 = "[^0-9$]";

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    // movies
                    String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                    if (nextLine != null) {
                        if ( !nextLine.matches(regex2)) {
                            i = nextLine;
                            System.out.println("Hello2");
                            System.out.println(i);

                        }
                        // date
                        while (nextLine != null && nextLine.matches(regex1)) {
                            System.out.println("Hello3");
                            if ( !nextLine.matches(regex1)) {
                                j = nextLine;
                                mov.add(nextLine);
                                System.out.println("Hello4");

                            }                           
                            nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                        }
                    }
                    Movie movie = new Movie(mov, i);
                    movies.add(movie);
                }   

             //   sc.close();
             } catch(Exception e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
             }
    }
}
```

1. This is needed:        `//movies = new ArrayList<movie>();`
2. Every time you call nextLine it will move the scanner point to the next line. So call it once a time and check if it match those regex.                       `String nextLine = sc.nextLine();`
3. Please check you whether the file path is specified.

Comment: I tried your code but it goes into an infinite loop (printing Hello3). Would it have something to do with the regex?

Comment: @user3162117 In the Hello3 loop, I don't get what's your purpose. I use the txt you provided above, and the code will never walk into this loop. I am not sure what input file cause this infinite loop. I just edit the code add "nextLine = sc.nextLine();" to get next line in the loop, does this help?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling sc.nextLine () in every check. Every NextLine () call reads next line.This means that you are checking one line and processing next line

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ReadFile
{
    Map<String, String> movies;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile();

        readFile.movies = new TreeMap<>();

        try
        {
            readFile.importData();

            printf(readFile.queryData("Der Anstandige"));

            printf(readFile.queryData("Bitter"));

            printf(readFile.queryData("blah"));

            printf(readFile.queryData("the"));
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            throw(e);
        }
    }

    void importData() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
    {
        LineNumberReader reader = null;

        File file = new File("c:/movie_release_dates.txt");

        try
        {
            reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file), 1024*64);    //

            String line;

            String date = null, movie = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.trim();

                if(line.equals("")) continue;

                if(line.matches(PATTERN_DATE))
                {
                    date = line;
                    date = strf("%s/%s", 
                                date.substring(date.length() - 4),
                                date.substring(0, date.length() - 5));

                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    movie = line.trim();
                }

                movies.put(movie, date);
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {

            throw(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    String queryData(String title)
    {
        String regex = "(?i)" + title.replaceAll("\\s", "\\s+");

        String[] matches = new String[movies.size()];

        int i = 0; for(Entry<String , String> movie : movies.entrySet())
        {
            String key = movie.getKey();
            String val = movie.getValue();

            if(key.matches(regex))
            {
                matches[i++] = strf("{movie=%s, date=%s}", key, val);
            }
            else if(key.toUpperCase().trim()
                       .contains(title.toUpperCase().trim()))
            {
                matches[i++] = strf("{movie=%s, date=%s}", key, val);
            }
        }

        String string = "";

        if(matches[0] == null)
        {
            string = "Not found\n";
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0; while(matches[i] != null)
            {
                string += matches[i++] + "\n";
            }
        }

        return string;
    }

    final String strf(String arg0, Object ... arg1)
    {
        return String.format(arg0, arg1);
    }

    final static void printf(String format, Object ... args)
    {
        System.out.printf(format, args);
    }

    final static void println(String x)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    final String PATTERN_DATE = "\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4}";
}
```

Console output:

    `{movie=Der Anstandige, date=2014/10/1}
    {movie=Bitter Honey, date=2014/10/3}
    Not found
    {movie=The Good Lie, date=2014/10/3}
    {movie=The Hero of Color City, date=2014/10/3}
    {movie=The Supreme Price, date=2014/10/3}`